# Problem in accessing the data of a dictionary at runtime in kivy gui with python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How I can access the data of the Dictionary "selected_items" of class "Item_Menu" when the data is transferred in the dictionary at run time according to the user Selection of checkboxes in the Kivy gui and I want to retrieve that data again in the another class "Description_item" for showing the data on another Screen in kivy when the button is pressed.

The whole source code:-

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
class my_mdcard(MDCard,RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior):
    pass

class Item_Menu(Screen,MDBoxLayout):
    list_of_information={"checkbox":[],"labels":[],"quantity":[]}
    selected_items= {"checkbox": [], "labels": [], "quantity": []}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Item_Menu,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(1,0.9)
        self.pos_hint={"top":1}
        self.orientation="vertical"
        scrollbarwin=ScrollView()
        content_box=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',padding=dp(8),spacing=dp(8),size_hint=(1,None))
        content_box.bind(minimum_height=content_box.setter('height'))
        for i in range(0,50):
            Template_card= my_mdcard(
                size_hint_y=None,
                size_hint_x=.960,
                height = dp(100),
                padding = dp(4),
                pos_hint={'center_y': .5, 'center_x': .490},
                radius = [20,],
                elevation = 4,

            )
            checkbox=MDCheckbox(
                size_hint=(None, None),
                size= (dp(48),dp(48)),
                pos_hint={'center_y': .5}
            )
            checkbox.bind(active=lambda instance,value:self.Selected_checkbox(instance,value))
            self.list_of_information["checkbox"].append(checkbox)
            image_box=MDBoxLayout(adaptive_size=True)
            image=FitImage(
                source="D:/Study/Python/Kivy/images/2.jpg",
                size_hint= (None, None),
                height=dp(80),
                width=dp(130),
                radius=[12,],
                pos_hint={'center_y':0.5}

            )
            image_box.add_widget(image)
            text_box=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical",adaptive_height=True,pos_hint={'center_y':0.5},padding=[12,0,0,0])
            item_name=MDLabel(text=f"item{i+1}",font_style="H5",size_hint=(1,None),bold=True,theme_text_color="Primary")
            item_name.bind(texture_size=item_name.setter('size'))
            self.list_of_information["labels"].append(item_name)
            price=MDLabel(text=u"Price: \u20B910/per",font_style="Subtitle1",size_hint=(1,None),bold=True,theme_text_color="Hint")
            price.bind(texture_size=price.setter('size'))
            quantitybox=MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical',adaptive_height=True,size_hint_x=0.2,pos_hint = {'center_y': .5,'center_x':0.5})
            quantityfield=MDTextField(
                hint_text= "Quantity",
                mode= "rectangle",
                size_hint=(None,None),
                width=dp(80),
                height= dp(40),
                padding=[0,0,15,0]
            )
            self.list_of_information["quantity"].append(quantityfield)
            quantitybox.add_widget(quantityfield)
            Template_card.add_widget(checkbox)
            Template_card.add_widget(image_box)
            Template_card.add_widget(text_box)
            text_box.add_widget(item_name)
            text_box.add_widget(price)
            Template_card.add_widget(quantitybox)
            content_box.add_widget(Template_card)
        scrollbarwin.add_widget(content_box)
        buttonbox=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical",pos_hint={"top":0.1},adaptive_height=True)
        button=MDRaisedButton(text="Selected!!!",size_hint=(1,0.2))
        
        button.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.Change_window(x))
        buttonbox.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(scrollbarwin)
        self.add_widget(buttonbox)
    def Selected_checkbox(self,instance,value):
        for i in range(0,len(self.list_of_information["checkbox"])):
            if instance==self.list_of_information["checkbox"][i] and value== True:
                self.selected_items["labels"].append(self.list_of_information["labels"][i])
                self.selected_items["quantity"].append(self.list_of_information["quantity"][i])
            elif instance==self.list_of_information["checkbox"][i] and value== False :
                self.selected_items["labels"].remove(self.list_of_information["labels"][i])
                self.selected_items["quantity"].remove(self.list_of_information["quantity"][i])
    def Change_window(self,instance):
        MyApp.sm.current="Item Description"
class Description_item(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Description_item,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print(Item_Menu.selected_items)
        wholeContentBoxContainer=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        for item in range(0,len(Item_Menu.selected_items["labels"])):
                label=MDLabel(text=Item_Menu.selected_items["labels"][item].text)
                print(Item_Menu.selected_items["labels"][item].text)
                quantity=MDLabel(text=Item_Menu.selected_items["quantity"][item].text)
                wholeContentBoxContainer.add_widget(label)
                wholeContentBoxContainer.add_widget(quantity)
        self.add_widget(wholeContentBoxContainer)
class MyApp(MDApp):
    sm=ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(Item_Menu(name="Item Menu"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Description_item(name="Item Description"))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        return self.sm


MyApp().run()
```

So how I can Access the data of the Dictionary which is taking the data at runtime.
if you have any solution for it. So, Please let me know also it will help me a lot. I will appericate your effors if you done this. Thank You!!

Comment: so you want selcect items then show their description on another screen ?

Comment: @medbenzekri yes you are right I want exactly that you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code was hard to debug but your problem was that your second screen `Description_item` was created at the beginning so it takes the dictionary `selected_items` empty
so you should create it when  Change_window is called:

```
   def Change_window(self,instance):
        MyApp.sm.add_widget(Description_item(name="Item Description"))
        MyApp.sm.current="Item Description"
```

and `MyApp` class is going to be as follows:

```
class MyApp(MDApp):
    sm=ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(Item_Menu(name="Item Menu"))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        return self.sm
```